# numpy.loadtxt converters parameter, using b'strings'

Tags: python, numpy

This is the first time a come across code using numpy.loadtxt. I read the official documentation, which states

> converters : dict, optional
>
> A dictionary mapping column number to a function that will parse the
> column string into the desired value. E.g., if column 0 is a date
> string: `converters = {0: datestr2num}`. Converters can also be used to
> provide a default value for missing data (but see also genfromtxt):
> `converters = {3: lambda s: float(s.strip() or 0)}`. Default: None.

What I understand is that it changes a string into a numerical value. But I don't understand clearly how it exactly works. The code is:

```
labels = [b'NO', b'DH', b'SL']
data = np.loadtxt('column_3C.dat', converters={6: lambda s: labels.index(s)} )
```

I don't understand the parameters inside converters.

I'd appreciate if anyone explain me how it works in this case.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` are complex, with only basic documentation.  I had to do quite a bit of digging to explain (for another SO) how `genfromtxt` handled missing and `nan` values.  Same goes for `converters`.

```
In [279]: labels = [b'NO', b'DH', b'SL']
     ...: txt = '1 NO\n2 DH\n3 SL'.splitlines()
     ...: data = np.loadtxt(txt, converters={1: lambda s: labels.index(s)} )
In [280]: data
Out[280]: 
array([[1., 0.],
       [2., 1.],
       [3., 2.]])
```

Often it helps to rewrite the `lambda` as function, and include some diagnostic prints.  There's more room for error testing and if/else cases as well.

```
In [281]: def foo(astr):
     ...:     print(astr)
     ...:     return labels.index(astr)
     ...: 
In [282]: labels = [b'NO', b'DH', b'SL']
     ...: txt = '1 NO\n2 DH\n3 SL'.splitlines()
     ...: data = np.loadtxt(txt, converters={1: foo} )
b'NO'
b'DH'
b'SL'
```

Note that the column values are passed, one at a time, to the `foo` as byte strings (the `b` prefix).  That's why `labels` also has to be byte strings.  This a legacy from Py2 when the default string type was bytes.

While `index` returns an integer, `loadtxt` applies its default `float` dtype to that.   We could change the return dtype to `int` (or a fancier structured one):

```
In [283]: labels = [b'NO', b'DH', b'SL']
     ...: txt = '1 NO\n2 DH\n3 SL'.splitlines()
     ...: data = np.loadtxt(txt, converters={1: foo} , dtype=int)
b'NO'
b'DH'
b'SL'
In [284]: data
Out[284]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 2]])
```

It's apparent from this that `converters` is applied to byte string values from the input, and `dtype` conversion is applied after.

---

Adding a string that isn't in `labels` gives us a further clue as to the action order:

```
In [289]: labels = [b'NO', b'DH', b'SL']
     ...: txt = '1 NO\n2 DH\n3 SL\n4 XX'.splitlines()
     ...: data = np.loadtxt(txt, converters={1: foo})
b'NO'
b'DH'
b'SL'
b'XX'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-289-a3450b85790b>", line 3, in <module>
    data = np.loadtxt(txt, converters={1: foo})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1139, in loadtxt
    for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1067, in read_data
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1067, in <listcomp>
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1126, in tobytes_first
    return conv(x.encode("latin1"))
  File "<ipython-input-281-64f4e6f34991>", line 3, in foo
    return labels.index(astr)
ValueError: b'XX' is not in list
```

It's `labels.index(b'XX")` that's raising the `ValueError`.

That error comes during this comprehension, which is applying `converters` to all `vals` of the row;

```
items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
```

For columns that we don't include in `converters`, `loadtxt` has probably added a function like this:

```
In [297]: def bar(astr):
     ...:     print(astr)
     ...:     return astr
     ...: 
In [298]: labels = [b'NO', b'DH', b'SL']
     ...: txt = '1 NO\n2 DH'.splitlines()
     ...: data = np.loadtxt(txt, converters={0: bar, 1: foo})
b'1'
b'NO'
b'2'
b'DH'
```

So roughly, `loadtxt` reads a line of the file, splits it on the `delimiter`.  It then applies `converters` to list of strings (`vals`).

It then appends this `items` list to a master list, and at then does a

```
np.array(x, dtype)
```

I thought it possible that it did a row by row `array` conversion, but the error message when `foo` returns a string instead of an error shows that the `array` conversion is done at the end (after all rows have been 'converted').

Alternatively it might just collect the `items` list, and do the array with dtype conversion once at the end.  I'd have to check the code for details.

If `dtype` is `None`, there's the added task of identifying a common dtype for each column, and creating a structured array from that.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's much more clear to me how it works.

Answer (score 3):

The converter defines a [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) that takes one parameter `s`. This is the column value (6th column in our case) read from the file, e.g. `'DH'`. This value is then passed to the `index` function of the `labels` list. `'DH'` is at position 1 in the list, so the function returns `1` which is then stored in the resulting array in column 6.

Example:

```
import io
import numpy as np

labels = [b'NO', b'DH', b'SL']

s = """0 1 2 3 4 5 NO
0 1 2 3 4 5 SL
0 1 2 3 4 5 DH"""
data = np.loadtxt(io.StringIO(s), converters={6: lambda s: labels.index(s)})
print(data)
#[[0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 0.]
# [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 2.]
# [0. 1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 1.]]
```

Please note that `loadtxt` will fail with a `ValueError` if it encounters values that are not in your list. So it might be better to use something like `converters={6: lambda s: labels.index(s) if s in labels else np.nan}` in this case.

Comment: Thank you. I just have a couple more questions. Converters returns ALL values from array as float numbers? Shouldn't it return a dict instead of list?

Comment: no, the converter returns whatever the function (which is the value of the dict, the key is the column number) returns. In our case it returns an `int`. As we didn't specify a `dtype` in `loadtxt` it uses the default type `float` for the resulting array, i.e. `1` is eventually converted to `1.0`